# Same hierarchy, different behaviour when accessing protected member of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected

I came across this code in a past exam:

```
#include <iostream>
class cls1
{
protected:
    int x;

public:
    cls1()
    {
        x = 13;
    }
};
class cls2 : public cls1
{
    int y;

public:
    cls2()
    {
        y = 15;
    }
    int f(cls2 ob)
    {
        return (ob.x + ob.y);
    }
};
int main()
{
    cls2 ob;
    std::cout << ob.f(ob);
    return 0;
}
```

This works just fine and outputs `28`. The problem is, it seems to contradict with this code (found in another exam):

```
#include <iostream>
class B
{
protected:
    int x;

public:
    B(int i = 28)
    {
        x = i;
    }
    virtual B f(B ob)
    {
        return x + ob.x + 1;
    }
    void afisare()
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
};
class D : public B
{
public:
    D(int i = -32)
        : B(i)
    {
    }
    B f(B ob)
    {
        return x + ob.x - 1;/// int B::x is protected within this context
    }
};
int main()
{
    B *p1 = new D, *p2 = new B, *p3 = new B(p1->f(*p2));
    p3->afisare();
    return 0;
}
```

It's the same type of hierarchy, but one has access to `ob.x` and the other one doesn't. Can someone explain to me why that is?

Comment: You probably want to read up on [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is, in the 1st case the `protected` member is accessed through the derived class. In the 2nd case the `protected` member is accessed through the base class, which is not allowed.

For [`protected` members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access),

(emphasis mine)

> A `protected` member of a class is only accessible
>
> 2) to the members `and friends (until C++17)` of any derived class of that class, but **only when the class of the object through which the protected member is accessed is that derived class or a derived class of that derived class**:
>
> ```
> struct Base {
>   protected:
>     int i;
>   private:
>     void g(Base& b, struct Derived& d);
> };
>
> struct Derived : Base {
>   void f(Base& b, Derived& d) { // member function of a derived class
>     ++d.i;                      // OK: the type of d is Derived
>     ++i;                        // OK: the type of the implied '*this' is Derived
> //  ++b.i;                      // error: can't access a protected member through
>                                 // Base (otherwise it would be possible to change
>                                 // other derived classes, like a hypothetical
>                                 // Derived2, base implementation)
>   }
> };
> ```